# accessing $router (ngNewRouter) inside function in module factory in Angular 1.4 doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following:

```
angular.module('app', [ 'ngNewRouter', 'security',
```

and security module

```
angular.module('security', ['ngNewRouter'])
    .factory('authService', ['$http', '$q', '$window', 'CONSTANTS', '$location', '$router', authService ]);

function authService($http, $q, $window, CONSTANTS, $location, $router) {
    var service = {};


    //tries to login user
    var _login = function(loginData) {
    var data = {
        "email": loginData.email,
        "password": loginData.password
    };
    $http.post(CONSTANTS.baseURL + '/login', data)
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            _authenticate(data);
            --->>> $router and $location --->>> not defined here, although $http, $q, $window, CONSTANTS are defined
        })
        .error (function (data, status, headers, config) {
            _logOut();
        });
};
```

Why is $router and $location not defined inside that function, and the others are?
What am I missing?

I also tried defining security module with and without ngNewRouter